# jQuery Bootstrap Dynamic Tabs (Add & Remove)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have my code which enables the user to add and remove tabs in Bootstrap UI Tabs.  I've successfully made it, and yes, it works well.

The only problem is it doesn't sort the tab name. For example, there are tabs like this: `Tab 1`, `Tab 2`, `Tab 3`, `Tab 4`, `Tab 5`

So when I remove `Tab 2`, `Tab 3` will be `Tab 2` then `Tab 4` will be `Tab 3`and so on..

Also, when I remove a tab, an active tab shows Tab 1. (Please see it in jsfiddle)

Any fix with my two problems?

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/cnycmLq0/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <button id="btn-add-tab" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Tab</button>
            </p>
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">Tab 1 content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tabID = 1;
        $('#btn-add-tab').click(function() {
            tabID++;
            $('#tab-list').append($('<li><a href="#tab' + tabID + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab ' + tabID + '<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button></a></li>'));
            $('#tab-content').append($('<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab' + tabID + '">Tab ' + tabID + ' content</div>'));
        });
        $('#tab-list').on('click', '.close', function() {
            var tabID = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
            $(this).parents('li').remove();
            $(tabID).remove();

            //display first tab
            var tabFirst = $('#tab-list a:first');
            tabFirst.tab('show');
        });

        var list = document.getElementById("tab-list");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just written a `function` to reset your `tabs` and change its `text`. The main part is to store the `button html` in a `var` and make both `button html` and `tabID` as global variables. You can call this `function` on `remove` event.

```
var button='<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button>';
var tabID = 1;
function resetTab(){
    var tabs=$("#tab-list li:not(:first)");//get all tabs except first tab
    var len=1;//we do not want to reset 1st tab
    $(tabs).each(function(k,v){
        len++;//increment it
        $(this).find('a').html('Tab ' + len + button); //replace each tabs html with latest index and button html.
    })
    tabID--;//decrement tabs count
}
```

## [`Complete solution in Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/cnycmLq0/1/)

Comment: Thank you for that! It works. But when I saw something wrong on your code. For example, I add 3 tabs. Then I removed Tab 2, so Tab 3 will be Tab 2. But when Tab 2 (old Tab 3) is active, it shows the content of Tab 3. Also, how can I go to the previous tab when tab is removed rather than going to the first tab?

Comment: That's valid I guess.. because if you are removing `tab2` you actually don't need the contents too.. So `tab3` will be basically the actual `tab` in place of `tab2` and its content holds valid...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/cnycmLq0/4/ I've updated it, fixed the content. But then when I removed the last tab, it doesn't show it's content. Can you help me please?

Comment: Because, there are duplicate `id`s for `tab`.. Give me some hours.. I'll come back and fix it..

Comment: @Jacob.. I still have a doubt... Would you mind explaining??